# How to get the boost::asio::async_read to return when the terminating character is reached

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

i'm using boost asio library to read the content from the tcp socket. My code looks like this

```
std::string completeBuffer="";
std::string TcpConnection::readMessage()
{
    LOG4CPLUS_DEBUG(logger, "Start Listener for Reading Message from Connection");
    boost::system::error_code error;
    boost::asio::async_read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(buffer),
        boost::bind(&TcpConnection::handleRead, this, buffer, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    return buffer.data();
}

void TcpConnection::handleRead(boost::array<char, TcpConnection::BUFFER_SIZE> buf, const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if(!error)
    {
       LOG4CPLUS_INFO(logger, "READ Message " << buf.data());
       completeBuffer.append(buf.data());
       buf.assign(0);
       readMessage();
    }

}
```

Now i'm making the call from some other class to `readMessage()`. whenever the `BUFFER_SIZE` is reached the `handleRead` gets called and the content gets appended.

now the question is say the `BUFFER_SIZE` is 50, and the whole message size is 75, `handleRead` is called only once and the buffer waits to be filled for the `handleRead` to be called for the second time.
Is there a way to set the EOM character or string for asio to return whenever its reached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer [async_read_until](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until/overload4.html)